# android dynamically change display coordinates for other apps

Tags: android, coordinates

-- Background:

We are working on a device called Run-n-Read which tracks a user's head movements and translates it to the appropriate text movement on the screen. The use is to help a person read while running on a treadmill or riding in a moving vehicle. You can check a small video on http://weartrons.com.

We have created a small device which contains accelerometer, a micro-controller and bluetooth to send the head location in real time to the tablet every ~17ms to match with the 60fps of display. We used Processing IDE to create a basic app with downloaded book pages to test the prototype.

-- PROBLEM:

We would like to run our app in the background and dynamically change the display coordinates of any other app contents on the screen, whether it's an eBook or twitter etc. Basically our algorithms are running on our external device and sending the display coordinates (in pixels to move up-down left-right) at about 60 times per second. We would like the Android display origin to move by that many pixels during every frame rendering.

I am an electronics engineer and it's my first stab at writing any piece of software, so please let me know if I was not clear or the answer is too obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android as OS makes sure applications are encapsulated and oblivious from each other. All inter-app communication is done through what is called `intents` which are in the end messages. And you have to know exactly the other apps declared intents and on top of that you have no assurances that all apps implemented the kind of feature you are requesting.
Therefore I don't think what you want to do (the coordinates change) is possible at all without tinkering with the OS source code and compiling your own version of Android.

Comment: Thanks ilomambo, we very much appreciate your prompt response. I understand that the ability to control how an app is displayed from another app will create havoc. Do you think we should get some open source e reader and put our code there for initial testing? Later, once others find our device useful, we can try to convince the popular eBook apps to include our code too. Thanks again.

Comment: @Weartrons First of all, you should gather more answers to this question. I do not consider myself an Android expert. Regarding the other issue, the eReader and  disclosing your code, it is a marketing decison, of yourself or your company. This is not defined as a discussion forum (see the FAQ) but you can open a chat room I guess on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ and get more opinions.